# Getting webdriver exception with selenium chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch the chrome browser and open my site login page,
so once the login pop up appears then this error comes and sometimes this error is not coming at the time login pop up,its coming middle of tests run that is after login has been done and tests starts running

I am using Testng,also in some of code lines I have used Thread.sleep

**ChromeVersion** : 75

**ChromeDriver** : 2.46 (Latest version of chrome driver giving some malicious protect error,so using this one)

**Error** : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

[image]

Comment: please add some more details

Comment: I have added some more details,please help

Comment: @chirag25, verify your proxy

Comment: @sgrillon : I am not using any proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

Change your chrome driver version (ChromeDriver 2.46 **NOT** Supports ChromeVersion 75).

See full documentation:
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

- ChromeDriver 2.46 Supports Chrome v71-73
- ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 Supports Chrome version 75
- ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 Supports Chromeversion 75
- ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140 Supports Chrome version 75

Comment: I tried using latest chromedriver but its giving me below error



**Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 15796
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.**

Comment: You can see ChromeDriverService service = new `ChromeDriverService.Builder().withWhitelistedIps(<--- with White listed Ips here --->).withVerbose(false).build();
           ... new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);`

Comment: @chirag25, **ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6** is only for **Chrome 74** an not **Chrome 75**

Comment: Thanks for replying..Yes its an blocking error as after this tests are not working and all get fail...I tried using Chrome 75 version driver also and getting same error